# Running react/node on ec2 with nginx not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a react and node application I'm trying to put on ec2. I have nginx installed and copied the application to `root/testing-123`. The application has a client folder for the react app and a server folder for the node app which uses

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/build')));
```

to show the react app.

I'm trying to set it up and have it run publicly. When I go to the Public IPv4 address I get the default nginx page. How can I get it to show the application?

(Many tutorials were saying to change the sites-available/default file, but I don't have that folder, instead I have nginx.conf, but I don't know what to edit in that file.)

Comment: You could disable Nginx and run the app port 443 and be fine if not comfortable tweaking those settings yet. The nginx.conf would contain your configurations, can't speak on where sites-available/default is at as some hosts do modify this process for you already.

Comment: So with that said you'll want to edit your config file, many guides on how to do this and remember to check for errors and restart service each time. But if out of your boundaries, do stop the service and re-run your application on port 80/443.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK I tried doing that but when I go to port 80 it just keeps on loading. The express app is listening to port 3001, and when I go there the same thing happens, it just keeps on loading

Comment: @Jessica Maybe you have `/etc/nginx/conf.d` folder? (see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/527630/difference-in-sites-available-vs-sites-enabled-vs-conf-d-directories-nginx) SF question) Does it contain any files?

Comment: This was a security issue. @BGPHiJACK Thanks for pointing me to the right direction! It's now working